# NodeJS Sockets Sometimes Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

So, I have a node server, running expressjs io (uses socket.io), and I'm building a grid map that tracks coordinates in a database.

Only, I've run into a peculiar issue in that my sockets only listen *sometimes*.

At first there was no error message, and only by chance I let the page run and I got this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '0' of undefined UkPS99A_w96Ae0K570Nt?t=1395276358213&i=0:1
```

When I click on the file `UkPS99A_w96Ae0K570Nt?t=1395276358213&i=0:1` I get this code:

```
io.j[0]("8::");
```

If I refresh the page, every few times it will suddenly work find for about 10 tile clicks, and then it stops working. My database is updating properly until the sockets basically die out.

Here is where I send the coordinates in my map:

```
io.emit("move", {x:this.x,y:this.y});
```

Server listening:

```
app.io.route('move', function(req) {
    con.getConnection(function(err){
        if (err) console.log("Get Connection Error.. "+err);
        //removed query because redundant
        req.io.emit("talk", {x:req.data.x,y:req.data.y});
    });
});
```

and my socket script:

```
io.on("talk",function(data) {
    console.log(data.x,data.y);
});
```

My script includes are at the bottom of the page in this order:

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>io = io.connect();</script> <!-- open the socket so the other scripts can use it -->
<script src="../js/sock.js"></script>
<script src="../js/map.js"></script>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong to that the socket seems to lose connection and throw some sort of error?

Update: I left the server running longer and a couple more error messages popped up in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of null socket.io.js:1967
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'close' of null socket.io.js:1967
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'onClose' of null
```

More update: altered the connection line and added the proper CORS to my server.js

```
io = io.connect('http://sourceundead.com', {resource : 'socket.io'});
```

Still the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a connection attrition as you never release them to the pool.

Assuming `con` is the (bad) name of your pool, instead of

```
app.io.route('move', function(req) {
    con.getConnection(function(err){
        if (err) console.log("Get Connection Error.. "+err);
        //removed query because redundant
        req.io.emit("talk", {x:req.data.x,y:req.data.y});
    });
});
```

you should have something like

```
app.io.route('move', function(req) {
    con.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        if (err) console.log("Get Connection Error.. "+err);
        //removed query because redundant
        req.io.emit("talk", {x:req.data.x,y:req.data.y});
        connection.release();
    });
});
```

Be careful that using connections must be done with care to ensure they're *always* released, and it's a little tedious to do especially when handling errors as soon as you have a few queries to do when doing a task.

At some point you might want to use promises to make that easier. Here's a blog post about [using bound promises to ease database querying in node.js](http://canop.org/blog/?p=516).