# Typescript spinner directive

Tags: angularjs, typescript, promise, directive

im trying to implement some type of a angularjs directive using TYPESCRIPT that will wrap every $http get request with a boolean parameter "isShow" that will watch the state of the request and update the parameter and show/hide the html element accordingly ( Without the use of $scope or $watch. )
Any idea how to achieve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the [promise disposer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915677/what-is-the-promise-disposer-pattern):

```
var spinnerSemaphore = 0;
function own(fn){
    spinnerSemaphore++;
    var res = $q.when(fn());
    fn().then(function(){ spinnerSemaphore--; }, 
            function(){ spinnerSemaphore--; });
    return res; 
}
```

Which would let you do:

```
own(function(){
    return $http.get(...); 
});
own(function(){
    return $http.get(...); 
});
own(function(){
    return $http.get(...); 
});
own(function(){
    return $timeout(...); // this also works, and anything else with promises
});
```

And bind showing the spinner to `spinnerSemaphore` (so falsey on 0 means hiding the spinner and more than 0 for showing it).

Comment: that's a nice answer benji

Comment: @phenomnomnominal thanks Craig, I was thinking of you when I wrote it. Also every other minute since then.

Comment: Benjamin,do i need some kind of a watch for the app to identify that the value of spinnerSemaphore was changed ?

Comment: @Basilf no, no need to do weird `$apply` stuff, angular promises already take care of that for you, you just have to bind to `spinnerSemaphore` which will define a watcher for you.

Comment: i see, it's just that the value for the ng-show for some reason does not get updated... hmmm..

Comment: I don't understand `fn.then(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a single spinner you can do that quite easily by binding its `ng-show` (or something equivalent) to `$http.pendingRequests.length`. Ofcourse this assumed you have `$http` in scope (or `$rootScope`).

Comment: barasat i dont use scope/rootscope in my app at all. thats my issue

Comment: Then put it on the root controller and use it like `rootCtrl.$http` ;)