# How to dispose resources in rejected promises with bluebird?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, promise, bluebird

How can I dispose the serial when the promise is rejected?

The dispose function prints error for rejected promises.

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot call method 'isOpen' of
>   undefined

```
var pingPort = function(port){
    return new promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var serial = new com.SerialPort(port.comName, {
            baudrate: 19200,
            parser: com.parsers.readline(lineEnd)
        }, false);
        serial.on("data", function(data){
            if (data === responseUuid){
                resolve(serial);
            }
        });
        serial.open(function(err){
            if (err){
                //reject(serial)
            }
            else{
                serial.write(pingUuid + lineEnd);
            }
        });
    });
};

var dispose = function(port){
    console.log(port.isOpen());
};

var findPort = function(){
    com.listAsync().map(function(port){
        return pingPort(port).timeout(100).catch(promise.TimeoutError, function(err) {
            console.log("Ping timout: " + port.comName);
            dispose(port);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.log("Ping error: " + port.comName);
            dispose(port);
        });
    }).each(dispose);
}();
```

Comment: There is not nearly enough context (or question) to answer this. The one obvious flaw is that port has to be `undefined` somewhere for that error to happen.

Comment: You say " ... dispose the serial ..." but `dispose()` accepts `port`. Which is it?

Comment: Yes sorry for the bad naming. i ended up removing bluebird and using callbacks instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question almost answers itself, in that "promise"  and "dispose" together beg you to consider the [Promise Disposer Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915677/), which is actually nothing more than judicious use of `.then()` or `.finally()` with a callback that disposes/closes something that was created/opened earlier.

With that pattern in mind, you will find it simpler to orchestrate disposal in `pingPort()` rather than `findPort()`.

Assuming the code in the question to be broadly correct, you can chain `finally()` as follows :

```
var pingPort = function(port) {
    var serial; // outer var, necessary to make `serial` available to .finally().
    return new promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        serial = new com.SerialPort(port.comName, {
            baudrate: 19200,
            parser: com.parsers.readline(lineEnd)
        }, false);
        serial.on('data', function(data) {
            if(data === responseUuid) {
                resolve(serial); //or resolve(port);
            }
        });
        serial.open(function(err) {
            if(err) {
                reject('failed to open');
            } else {
                serial.write(pingUuid + lineEnd);
            }
        });
    })
    .finally(function() { // <<<<<<<<<<<
        serial.close(); // "dispose".
    });
};
```

Unlike .then, .finally's handler doesn't modify the value/reason, so can be placed in mid-chain without the need to worry about returning a value or rethrowing an error. This point is rather poorly made in the Bluebird documentation.

With disposal in `pingPort()`, `findPort()` will simplify as follows :

```
var findPort = function(){
    com.listAsync().map(function(port) {
        return pingPort(port).timeout(100)
        .catch(promise.TimeoutError, function(err) {
            console.log("Ping timout: " + port.comName);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log("Ping error: " + port.comName);
        });
    });
}();
```

Going further, you may want to do more with the array of promises returned by `.map()`, but that's another issue.