# Chaining of promises in PromiseKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, promise, promisekit

I have the following scenario:

1. Request a token from the server
2. Execute a request, i.e. getAllNews
3. Parse the response of the request getAllNews
4. Persist the parsed data
5. Delete the requested token

and I do these 5 operations using promises:

```
return [self createToken].then(^(NSString *token) {
    return [self performRequestGetAllNewsUsingToken:token];
}).then(^(id responseObject) {
    return [self parseNewsResponse:responseObject];
}).then(^(NewsResponseObject *newsResponseObject) {
    return [self persistNewsFromArray:newsResponseObject.allNews inContext:self.context];
}).finally(^{
    [self deleteToken:token];
});
```

The problem that I face is that I cannot send parameters to `finally` - this `token` parameter is missing.

I thought about calling `deleteToken` as a `then`, immediately after `[self performRequestGetAllNewsUsingToken:token]`, but it will only execute the operation if previous one resolved to an actual result and not an error.
I should destroy the tokens regardless of what was the outcome of the request and no matter if it was executed successfully or not.

Is there a way to set a rule that If `createToken` is executed, then `deleteToken` should be called no matter what, but only after executing my normal request `getAllNews`?

Comment: Sounds like you need the [promise disposer pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915677/). Worked example in the reference is javascript but the problem seems to be identical to the one here.

Comment: Also very related in JS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the token in a closure so you have access to it in the finally clause:

```
NSString* token; 
return [self createToken].then(^(NSString *token_) {
    token = *token_;
    return [self performRequestGetAllNewsUsingToken:token];
}).then(^(id responseObject) {
    return [self parseNewsResponse:responseObject];
}).then(^(NewsResponseObject *newsResponseObject) {
    return [self persistNewsFromArray:newsResponseObject.allNews inContext:self.context];
}).finally(^{
    [self deleteToken:token];
});
```

Comment: I read about the disposer pattern, but could not figure out how can I apply it with my current example. Can you please give me some more information about a possible solution? This will help verify that the token is always destroyed.