# Does .then(Promise.mapSeries(...)) behave differently than .then(function() { return Promise.mapSeries(...); })?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I initially assumed that passing a bare `Promise.mapSeries(...)` call as an argument to `.then()` would be the same as wrapping it in a function, like `.then(function() { return Promise.mapSeries(...); })`.  Having written out this question, I'm no longer entirely sure why it works at all.

In the simplified code below, I open a couple of databases asynchronously (`openDBAsync()`) and then read a file containing a JS object.  I use `_.map()` to iterate over all of the key/value pairs in the object and asynchronously update their values in a database, while keeping track of which ones meet certain criteria (whether the value is odd, in this toy example).  `Promise.all()` waits for all of the async database calls to settle, and then `Promise.mapSeries()` is used to process each of the subset of keys, which makes another async database call for each one.  Finally, I close all the databases.

```
function processData(path)
{
    var oddKeys = [];

    return openDBAsync()
        .then(function() { return readFileAsync(path); })
        .then(function(dataObject) {
            return Promise.all(_.map(dataObject, function(value, key) {
                if (value % 2) {
                    oddKeys.push(key);
                }

                return updateDBAsync(key, ++value);
            }))
            .then(Promise.mapSeries(
                oddKeys,
                function(key) {
                    return updateOddDBAsync(key);
                }
            ))
        })
        .then(closeDBAsync);
}
```

The problem is that the database throws errors complaining that I'm trying to update the database after it's been closed.  That means that some of the promises generated in the `.mapSeries()` call are being called after the final `closeDBAsync()`.  I expected all of them to settle before the final `.then()` call.

If I wrap the call to `Promise.mapSeries()` in a function:

```
            .then(function() {
                return Promise.mapSeries(
                    oddKeys,
                    function(key) {
                        return updateOddDBAsync(key);
                    }
                );
            })
```

Then I don't get any errors.  It also works if I put a `.delay(2000)` before the close database call, which indicates that `Promise.mapSeries()` isn't settling all of the promises before it finishes.

This seems like either a bug in Bluebird, or, much more likely, I'm not understanding something fundamental about how `Promise.mapSeries()` works.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Without the function it will run right away when `oddKeys` is not ready to be consumed. It just looks like an anti-pattern to push things to an array within a promise to then make use of it in another promise. Why not thread this data asynchronously?

Comment: `.then(Promise.mapSeries(...))` will invoke `mapSeries` immediately and pass *its result* into `.then(...)` to be called later. Your argument to `mapSeries` is not a promise, so it will map that argument immediately. Follow elclanrs's advice and restructure this without side-effects (e.g. one thenable to just collect the odd keys and another to process them, without keeping an external state variable).

Comment: Thanks, @elclanrs and @DCoder. I agree that having the array outside of the promise thread is not ideal. But the direct call to `Promise.mapSeries()` **doesn't** get applied to the array immediately. If it was, the array would be empty and this code wouldn't work at all. Looking at the Bluebird code, there's some logic I don't entirely understand that decides when to start iterating on the array. I'm wondering if something about this logic could get confused about when it's finished mapping the array.

Comment: Are you by any chance calling processData multiple times ? That could cause 1 async close db statement to interrupt another processData call.

Comment: I am calling `processData()` multiple times, but in the real code, the calls to open and close the database are called only once, outside of this function. I'd included the calls in this function just to simplify the description.

Comment: I tried to build a standalone code snippet to reproduce this issue (which is something you should have provided, actually, for accurate results). It shows that calling `.then(Promise.mapSeries(...))` doesn't work as you think it does, and it even emits a console warning: `.then() only accepts function, but was passed: [object Object]`, because `.mapSeries` returns a promise, which cannot be used as a `.then()` callback.

Comment: Thanks, @DCoder. When running the actual code in Node, I didn't see any such warning, which would definitely have been helpful. Do you have to do something special to enable warnings in Bluebird? I see that its `warn()` method maps to `console.log()`, and I see my log messages and Bluebird errors in the console, but don't seem to see its warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> much more likely, I'm not understanding something fundamental about how `Promise.mapSeries()` works

Nope, this seems to be more a misunderstanding about how `.then(…)` works.

The `then` method of promises does always take a *callback function* (if you're passing anything else [but `null`], Bluebird should spit out a warning!). By calling `.then(Promise.mapSeries(…))`, you were passing a promise instead, which is simply *ignored*. Being ignored, it also is not awaited by anything, which leads to that error of the database being closed too early.

> But the direct call to `Promise.mapSeries()` **doesn't** get applied to the array immediately. If it was, the array would be empty and this code wouldn't work at all.

Yes it does. Your array is filled from by the `_.map` callback, which is executed synchronously, before `then` and `mapSeries` are invoked.

So the solution is indeed to wrap the call in a function expression, which will only be executed when the `Promise.all(…)` fulfills, and whose result will *then* not be ignored but rather awaited. There might be more, different solutions, depending on what degree of parallel execution you want to allow.

Btw, given you are doing a database transaction, your current code is quite fragile. Look into the [promise disposer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28915677/1048572).

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi. Obvious when you point it out that the `_.map()` runs synchronously. I think I was confusing myself because it was wrapped in a `Promise.all()`, which made my brain think "this bit happens later". I'll take another look at disposers, though the documentation was a bit abstruse last time I checked it out.