# Implementing page loader in Angular using promise

Tags: angularjs, promise, loader

I am wondering what would be the best way to implement a function, that would be responsible for toggling a gif on certain requests. I don't want to display it on all of the http requests, so I don't want to place it within the interceptor - I want to create a service.

I was most likely going to go with a function that will work as following:

```
LoaderFunction(SomeFunction())
```

Which will toggle a img or whatever whenever the promise is initiated and resolved. The `SomeFunction()` will usually be http requests, which already have their own promise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a counting semaphore and [the disposer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915677/what-is-the-promise-disposer-pattern). It would work for any number of ongoing requests.

```
withLoader.count = 0;
function withLoader(fn){
     if(count === 0) initiateLoader();
     count++;
     return $q.when(fn).finally(function(){
         count--;
         if(count === 0) finishLoader();
     });
}
```

This binds a scope to the lifetime of an event - like RAII in C++. This'd let you do:

```
withLoader(someFunction);
withLoader(someFunction);
withLoader(function(){
    return $http.post(...); 
}).then(function(){
   // http request finished, like your normal `then` callback
});
```

The loader would finish when the counter reaches 0, that is when *all* requests finish.

Since it's Angular, you probably want to put `withLoader` in its own service and have a directive manage the loading itself.

Comment: This is very similar to what I ended up doing. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *easiest* way to do it is through the use of promises on the `$http` calls **themselves**.

**Example:**

```
$http.post("/", data, function() {
  initiateLoader(); // this is a function that starts the loading animation.
}).success(function (data) {
  finishLoader(); // this is a function that ends the loading animation.
}).catch(function(err) {
  finishLoader(); //so the loader also finishes on errors.
});
```

Comment: I think this is not the best way to implement this - imagine what would happen if you would have many requests at the same time - they would get into a conflict, and toggle themselves on and off even though some requests are not finished.

Comment: Good point for sure, one way to fix that would be to give an ID to the loaders & pass that into the function, instead of using the same loader for all the different requests.

Comment: Instead of using a combination of `.success` and .`catch` you could use jquery's `.always`