# Promise-MySQL cannot release connections back to the pool

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise

I am very new to Node.js development and I am working on an app that requires me to pull users from a mysql database. I am using the `promise-mysql` library to query a mysql database. I am trying to use a connection pool like this:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host:     hgh.host,
  user:     hgh.user,
  password: hgh.pw,
  database: hgh.name,
  connectionLimit: 10
});
```

As a global variable in my module.

I then have the above function to return a connection from the pool.

```
function connect() {
  return pool.getConnection().then(function(connection) {
    return connection
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Connect failed");
    throw ErrorModel.generateErrorObject(error, 500);
  });
}
```

Below is a function I am using to query the database with:

```
function getUser(username) {
  var sql_query = `SELECT * FROM userstable WHERE userName = ` + `'` + username + `'`;
  return connect().then(function(conn) {
    return conn.query(sql_query).then(function(rows) {
      console.log("HGH getUser Then");
      console.log(pool);
      conn.release();
      return rows;
    });
  }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("HGH getUser Catch");
      console.log(error);
      throw ErrorModel.generateErrorObject(error, 500);
  });
}
```

I am getting this issue:

`conn.release` is not a function when trying to release my current connection into the pool. Is my logic wrong here? My goal is to have a pool with a bunch of connections (up to a certain number) and if a user needs to query, the `getConnection()` function just grabs them either a free connection from the pool, or creates them one. Problem is I cannot for the life of me release it back to the pool as `free`..Every time I make a request with `conn.end()` instead of `release` the connection remains in the `_allConnections` array of the pool when I console it out, and there are absolutely no connections in the `_freeConnections` array.

Anyone know how I can make connections free again??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the module's code I found the function for releasing a connection from a pool:

```
pool.prototype.releaseConnection = function releaseConnection(connection) {
    //Use the underlying connection from the mysql-module here:
    return this.pool.releaseConnection(connection.connection);
};
```

So if all of these functions live in the same file you could do the following in the getUser function:
replace

```
conn.release();
```

with

```
pool.releaseConnection(conn);
```

Comment: Oh I missed that one! Better solution than mine =D

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. Would there be a way to release the connection, in the connection method so I wouldn't have to re-write something every time I want to write a method that uses `connect()` to query?

Comment: I would make a generic query(queryString) function that fetches a connection, runs the query,  returns the connection to the pool and then returns the results from the query. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @DomFarolino,"Would there be a way to release the connection, in the connection method ...". Try try the [Disposer Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915677/what-is-the-promise-disposer-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code, `promise-mysql` wraps the original connection object, which doesn't expose the `release` method. However, the original is exposed as a property called `connection`, so this works:

```
conn.connection.release();
```

A few random thoughts:

- You should probably [escape](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#escaping-query-values) your query input:

  ```
  var sql_query = `SELECT * FROM userstable WHERE userName = ${ pool.escape(username) }`;
  ```
- Your code doesn't release connections when an error occurs (because the code in the `.then()` callback wouldn't get called); it's better to use [`.finally()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html) to do the releasing, as that will get called for both resolved *and* rejected cases:

  ```
  function connect() {
    var conn = null;
    return pool.getConnection().then(function(connection) {
      conn = connection;
      return connection;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Connect failed", error);
    }).finally(function() {
      if (conn) {
        conn.connection.release();
      }
    });
  }
  ```

Comment: Yeah I was using conn.end() in a finally earlier for testing, not sure why I reverted it. And yes I wasn't escaping because we only run this query if that use exists in another database. We check if they do through an API call on another internal company application however that's a good idea thanks, can never be too safe