# How to use promises in an interactive call?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I'm retrieving a form (via XMPP, XEP-0004), creating an interactive form dialog for it, then submitting the form when the dialog is closed.

The code (roughly approximated for simplicity):

```
function form(name, callback) {
  server.getForm(name, function(response) {
    callback(response.formFields, function (data) {
      server.submitForm(name, data);
    });
  });
}

function main() {
  form('example', function(fields, callback) {
    var dialog = ui.formDialog(fields);
    dialog.addButton('submit', function(data) {
      callback(data);
    });
    dialog.show();
  });
}
```

Note how the caller and callee exchange callbacks - in one direction, for the fields retrieved from the server; in the other, for the user-submitted data.

I've recently discovered JS Promises and I'd like to know if they could replace the callbacks more elegantly.

I got as far as:

```
function form(name) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    server.getForm(
      name,
      (response) => { resolve(response.formFields) },
      reject
    );
  });
}

function main() {
  form('example').then((fields) => {
    var dialog = ui.formDialog(fields);
    dialog.addButton('submit', /* ... */);
  });
}
```

But now I'm stuck, because I have no way to pass the submit button's event back to the `form()` call.

I can't simply create a Promise for the dialog either, because I'd have to create that promise first in order to pass it to `form()`, but I need the promise returned by `form()` to be resolved before I can create the dialog. There's a sort of bootstrap problem.

Is there some way to use promises here, or should I stick with passing callbacks back and forth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could break the problem into three parts:

1. `form` - Retrieve the form - function that takes name and returns Promise resolved with the fields.
2. `askUser` - Gather input - function that takes fields, displays form and returns a Promise with the submitted data.
3. `submit` - Submit form - function that takes data and returns a Promise of network result.

You can than compose the three together:

```
form('example')
  .then(askUser)
  .then(submit)
  .catch(errorHandler)
```

Which would return a Promise eventually resolved with the submit operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can still pass callback along the response. Simply pass array of response and callback to the `resolve`. And within `.then` callback you might destruct the array. In short you can write something like: `response => resolve([response.formFields, **your_callback**])` and `.then(([fields, callback]) ...`. But in my opinion the code is smelly and you should decompose `from` function into two independent functions to avoid passing callback back and forth

Answer (score 1):

`form` wraps its behaviour around a callback, you cannot really avoid that callback without splitting `form` in two functions. However, it's totally fine - it's known as the [disposer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28915677/1048572).

You'd use it like this:

```
function form(name, callback) {
  return server.getForm(name).then(function(response) {
    return callback(response.formFields);
  }).then(function (data) {
    return server.submitForm(name, data);
  }).catch(function(e) {
    console.error(e); // or display it in the form, or whatever
  });
}

function main() {
  return form('example', function(fields) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var dialog = ui.formDialog(fields);
      dialog.addButton('submit', resolve);
      dialog.show();
    });
  });
}
```