# Is it possible to flatten this Promise chain any further?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

As part of a small node application I wrote this function that saves something to a database (clearly an async operation) using [mysql/mysqljs](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql):

```
function persist(values) {
  getConnection()
    .then(connection => {
      const {fistName, lastName} = values
      const query = mysql.format(
        'INSERT INTO names VALUES(NULL, ?, ?)',
        [fistName, lastName]
      )

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.query(query, (err, results, fields) => {
          connection.release()

          if (err) {
            reject(err)
          }

          resolve([results, fields])
        })
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err)
    })
}
```

`getConnection` is actually a version of mysqljs/mysql's [getConnection function](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) that I promisified [using Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html).

While this works, it still seems a bit clunky to me because of my use of the Promise constructor. At the moment this is the only solution I was able to come up with due to the special signature of `connection.query` (callback second).

Is there a way to further flatten this chain to make it more readable while staying compatible with `connection.query`'s signature?

Comment: This might be a better fit for Code Review Stack Exchange: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: a) move the promise constructor thing into a separate helper function b) use a custom promisifier in Bluebird

Comment: I very strongly recommend that you never use automatic semicolon insertion.

Comment: This code only consists of `getConnection().then().catch()`.  There's nothing to flatten as there is no nesting here.  The query depends upon the `getConnection()` result so it has to be executed inside the `.then()`.  Nothing to flatten there either.

Comment: For a much simpler `persist()`, try the [disposer pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28915678/3478010). You will end up with more lines of code overall, but amongst them will be a reusable `withDb()` function.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Wow thank you, this is awesome! My brain is currently melting while trying to understand this, but this seems to be a proper solution!

Comment: You still need a custom promisification of `connection.query()` but that can be looked after in your `getConnection()` function allowing both `withDb()` and `persist()`. to be very light weight.