# ES6 Javascript Promise - execute after .then() is called

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, callback, promise, es6-promise

If you want to execute code after a callback is called in JavaScript, then you can just place it after the callback:

```
function demoCallback(callback) {
  callback()
  console.log("I execute second")
}

demoCallback(() => {
  console.log("I execute first")
})
```

Is it possible to do the same thing with an ES6 Promise from within the scope of the function? Let's say I have a function that returns a Promise:

```
function demoPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve()
    console.log("I execute first")
  })
}

demoPromise().then(() => { console.log("I execute second") })
```

The Code inserted after **resolve** executes once the Promise is resolved, but *before* **then** is called outside the scope of the function. **Is there a way that I can execute code after both, but do so from within the scope of the function?**

Comment: It will still run, but not necessarily before the then.

Comment: It's really unclear what you asking here, `resolve` is something you control, you decide when to resolve your promise,..  So in the above if you want  `first / second`,. just change the order `console.log("first"); resolve();`

Comment: You can pass a function to `resolve` and call that function in `then`

Comment: @Keith perhaps I bolded the wrong question. I'm asking (specifically) the question that is bolded at the bottom. Can I execute code after the Promise resolves and .then() is called, but from within the scope of the function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to do the same thing with an ES6 Promise from within the scope of the function?

No, this isn't possible. `then` callbacks always run asynchronously, and that includes being asynchronous in regard to the `resolve()` call.

(That said, promise callbacks are queued, so you can abuse that queue to get your code behind the other:

```
function demoPromise() {
  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
      p.then(() => {
        console.log("I execute second");
      }); // because I will be scheduled second
    }, 1000);
  });
  return p;
}

demoPromise().then(() => {
   console.log("I execute first");
}); // because I was scheduled first
```

But please don't do that)

> If you want to execute code after a callback is called in JavaScript

then you probably should not just return a promise. Take a callback that does what you want before executing your code:

```
function demoPromise(callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  }).then(() => {
    return callback();
  }).then(res => {
    console.log("I execute second");
  });
}

demoPromise(() => {
   console.log("I execute first");
}).then(() => {
   console.log("I execute last");
});
```

This is known as the [disposer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28915677/1048572) and very useful for handling resources.

Answer (score 2):

You can resolve the Promise with a function that can be called in a **then** block. So long as that function is called within the block, you can execute code before it like so

```js
function demoPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(function(){
        console.log("I execute second")
    });
  })
}

demoPromise().then(f => { console.log("I execute first");f();})
```

Comment: Sadly, even that little `;f();` is too much code :-) -- the point of a disposer is that it cleans up regardless of what the calling code does; if the caller has to remember to call a callback then Murphy's Law says that sooner or later, they won't.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
    demoPromise().then(()=>{
        console.log('I execute first')
    }).then(() =>{
        console.log('I execute second')
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.error(err)
    }).finally(()=>{
        console.log('I execute last')
    })
```