# Catch all block in nested promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Is there a way to add a catch all block to run after an entire promise chain? In the example below, `get` is a generic lib method that handles some data processing and returns the data to `callGet` which takes the data and handles the UI in whatever way. I want to make a catch all error handling block that runs after the entire chain runs. I want the catch all `finally` block to live on the `get` block because it is the generic lib method.

```
// generic lib method used throughout codebase
function get(url, data) {
    return axios.get(url, data).then(res => {
        // handle response in whatever way (1)
    }).catch(error => {
        // handle error in whatever way (2)
    }).finally(() => {
        // RUN BLOCK AFTER callGet CHAIN (3)
    });
}

// specific call from somewhere within the codebase
function callGet() {
    get('/test', {}).then(res => {
        // do more with response from get (4)
    }).catch(err => {
        // handle error in UI somehow (5)
    });
}

callGet();
```

If this were a single chain written out, the order would run like this:
(I know this isn't how promises work - just pseudocode to write out the thoughts)

```
axios.get(url, data).then(res => {
    // (1) then in get block
}).then(res => {
    // (4) then in callGet block
}).catch(err => {
    // (2) catch in get block if errors in get block
}).catch(err => {
    // (5) catch in callGet block if errors in callGet block
}).finally(() => {
    // (3) run after callGet block
})
```

---

Update:

Ultimately ended up going with bluebird's onPossiblyUnhandledRejection http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.onpossiblyunhandledrejection.html

It ends up doing what I need it to to catch any unhandled rejections that the dev isn't specifically handling.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific here because what it seems like you're asking for doesn't make any sense.  `callGet()` calls `get()`, but you're asking for `get()` to do something when `callGet()` is done.  That doesn't make any sense.  `get()` is the child and the child has no way of knowing when the parent (the caller) is done with whatever it's doing.  All the child `get()` knows is when it is done.  It knows nothing about its caller.

Comment: Presumably, you shouldn't be organizing things this way.  Or, you need to create some event that `get()` can register some code for that `callGet()` will emit when it's done and you pass in the emitter to `get()` so it can hook up to it.  With real code (not pseudo-code), we could probably suggest a better code organization, but there is no answer to the theoretical question you pose because that's not possible.  `get()` doesn't know anything about it's caller.

Comment: You're probably looking for the [promise disposer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915677/what-is-the-promise-disposer-pattern)

Comment: @jfriend00 essentially what i'm looking for is a catch all for unhandled rejections that the dev might miss so the default behavior would be to redirect to a static error page. i ended up going with bluebird's onPossiblyUnhandledRejection http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.onpossiblyunhandledrejection.html

Comment: Well, your question would have gotten a number of on-topic answers if that's actually the question you asked.  Nowhere in your question does it say that's what you wanted.

Comment: yep, and that's my fault. i couldn't think of the right words to describe what i was looking until i did more digging. apologize for the unspecific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible in the way you want it.

The reason is simple: the hierarchy of those `.then`s is different.

To make it easier to understand, imagine, that it's all synchronous (it isn't, and shouldn't be; that's just a thought experiment). Without the `catch` and `finally`, it would look like this:

```js
function callGet(){
  try{
  // vvvvvvvvvvvv--- for sake of simplicity, assume that it's here (although it isn't)
    (function get(...){
      axios.get(...)
      // (1) then in get block
    })(...)
    // (4) then in callGet block
  }catch(err){
    // (5) catch in callGet block if errors in callGet block
  }
}
```

To add the `catch` and `finally`, you'd have to change it into something like this:

```js
function callGet(){
  try{
    try{
      try{
      // vvvvvvvvvvvv--- for sake of simplicity, assume that it's here (although it isn't)
        (function get(...){
          axios.get(...)
          // (1) then in get block
        })(...)
        // (4) then in callGet block
      }catch(err){
        // (2) catch in get block if errors in get block
      }
    }catch(err){
      // (5) catch in callGet block if errors in callGet block
    }
  }finally{
    // (3) run after callGet block
  }
}
```

That's all nice, and actually, it would work, but (unfortunately, there **is** a "*but*") now just try to move the `catch (2)` and the `finally (3)` *into the `get` function*. **There's clearly no way to do so** (without messing up their order)!

With promises, there *would* be a very hacky and complicated way to do *something similar* to it, but just let it alone, and let me explain why you *shouldn't* do that.

---

Every function should do its own job. Preferably **one** job. Your `get` function has nothing to do with the UI, etc. (at least it shouldn't have). Its job is to make a network request, maybe process the response and handle errors. However, it should only handle its own errors, **but not its caller's**.

If it were in the way you want, the `catch` of `get`  (`2`) would also capture and handle the errors thrown in `callGet` (`4`), while **leaving only the errors thrown from *that `catch` handler (`2`)* for `callGet`'s `catch` (`5`)**.

That would make your code complicated, unsemantic, unreliable, and therefore hard to maintain.

The best you can do is to either handle the error by yourself in `get`, or to leave the error handling to the caller and don't try to mess up with your caller's job. If you're writing a library, you may offer helper methods for the caller, that composes promises in some unique way, but it's up to the caller to decide whether to use it or not.

If you want to enforce that anyway, you might use a different programming pattern for that (I'm not the good person to ask which), JS is flexible enough to let you implement it.

Answer (score -1):

Just rethrow the error in the first catch block if you want to handle it further in the following catch chains;

```
function get(url, data, onFulfilledHook, onRejectedHook) {
    return axios.get(url, data).then(res => {
        // handle response in whatever way (1)
    })
     .then(onFulfilledHook)
     .catch(error => {
        // handle error in whatever way (2)

        throw error; // rethrow the error <<<<<<<<<<<
    })
    .catch(onRejectedHook)
    .finally(() => {
        // RUN BLOCK AFTER callGet CHAIN (3)
    });
}

function callGet() {
    get('/test', {}, res => {
        // do more with response from get (4)
    }, err => {
        // handle error in UI somehow (5)
    });
}
```

Comment: That won't do the desired result. I need it to run the `finally` block *after* the catch in the `callGet` method. I'm not worried about the catch method being called.

Comment: You can pass `then` and `catch` functions as callbacks to the get function. But I'm pretty sure the problem is bad architecture.

Comment: Agree with Dmitriy, even if you get that working the code will not be understandable.  Usually the better approach is to let the callers decide how they want to handle the errors, if there is a lot duplicate code you could create a function that is invoked by the callers in their catch blocks.