# How to throw an exception when an object is not disposed?

Tags: javascript, typescript

As I understand, there is no destructors in typescript unlike most languages. I have an object in my tests which initialize a connection to the database. **What approach should I take in order to make sure the programmer called the method disconnect before the test ends?**

Is there a way to make the object autonomous in the detection of connection leaks, or is the only option to remember to call in the `afterAll` block. What do people usually do?

Comment: You could mock the method. That said, this is pretty broad. Which frameworks/libraries are you using? A [mcve] of the relevant code under test/test framework would go a long way to clarify what you're dealing with here.

Comment: Depending on the test framework and your coding style: a) use the [disposer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28915677/what-is-the-promise-disposer-pattern) instead of `.connect()` and `.disconnect()` methods b) just call `afterAll` from the `getInitialisedConnection()` test helper c) use a linter rule that catches the missing cleanup.

Comment: This sounds like a pretty standard mocking problem. `sinon` for example has a way to detect if a function was called. Isn't that what you're after?

Comment: It's a functional test, I will not mock the database, also I wanted to know in general what is the common practice for connection handling objects in typescript, I'll try @Bergi proposition, looks like a solution to my problem, thanks for the solution!