# Convert async callback to an async generator pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, dispose

I have below function from a 3rd party package which I can't modify

```
async function runTransaction(callback) {
   const client = await createClient();
   try {
       await client.query("BEGIN");
       await callback(client);
   } finally {
       await client.query("COMMIT");
   }
}
```

Normally I have to create an async function and pass it to the `runTransaction`

```
async function update(client) {
   await client.query("UPDATE ...")
}


await runTransaction(update);
```

I wonder if there is a way to use `runTransaction` in an async generator pattern. Here is my sketch. The end result I want is `BEGIN` then `UPDATE` then `COMMIT`

```
async *clientGenerator() {
   await runTransaction(async client => {
      yield client
   });
   // this will not work as yield can't be used in a callback
}


async function main() {
   const dbClientGenerator = await clientGenerator();
   const dbClientHolder = await dbClientGenerator.next();
   await dbClientHolder.value.query("UPDATE ...");
}
```

I also tried below, but the callback gets called at the same time as `await client.query("COMMIT");` in `runTransaction`.

```
async *clientGenerator() {
   yield new Promise(resolve => {
      runTransaction(async client => {
          resolve(sql);
      })
    })
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write<sup>1</sup>

```
async function* transaction() {
    const client = await createClient();
    try {
        await client.query("BEGIN");
        yield client;
    } finally {
        await client.query("COMMIT");
    }
}
```

and use it as

```
for await (const client of transaction()) {
    await client.query("UPDATE ...");
}
```

but this is **no better (and much more confusing)** than the current

```
await runTransaction(async client => {
    await client.query("UPDATE ...");
});
```

Really there is nothing wrong with this. It is known as the [promise disposer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28915677/1048572) and guarantees proper cleanup of resources after you're done. Your `main` function that manually advances the async iterator is a prime example of what's wrong with this approach: it fails to do error handling and would never commit the transaction. The promise disposer pattern prevents such abuse.

The pattern may get superseded by disposables from the [*explicit resource management* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-explicit-resource-management) which will allow writing

```
{
    await using client = transaction();
    await client.query("UPDATE ...");
}
```

<sub>1: or even wrap the `runTransaction` you're given into an equivalent of this, instead of rewriting it, but this is complicated and I wanted to make the point clear.</sub>

---

If you absolutely have to do this, here's how:

```
async function* transaction() {
    // © Bergi, https://stackoverflow.com/a/78043294/1048572, CC BY-SA 4.0
    let final, result, resume; 
    const client = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        final = runTransaction(client => {
            resolve(client);
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                resume = resolve;
            });
        })
        final.catch(reject);
    })
    try {
        result = yield client;
    } catch(err) {
        result = Promise.reject(err);
    } finally {
        resume(result);
        return final;
    }
}
```

This handles all kinds of possible failure cases in `runTransaction` and in the <s>callback</s> iteration, but relies on `runTransaction` calling the callback exactly once (unless there's an error in `createClient`).

Comment: Thanks, but as the question said, `runTransaction` is a method from 3rd party package and I can't modify. I know it will be possible if I can modify it. Any idea how to achieve it without modifying `runTransaction`

Comment: Yes, I have an idea, but this answer is meant to be a frame challenge. Doing this is a bad idea and I would not recommend it. Why do you still want to do it?

Comment: It is requested by other team who has done this pattern and they can't change easily.  we need to provide this solution and also under the restriction that we can't modify the 3rd party method

Comment: I would recommend to challenge their request. Changing from async iteration to an awaited function call should be an easy change. Why did they start using async generators for this in the first place?

Comment: They have their restrictions. We don't have much choice so I'm still asked to try to figure this out. They have very large codebase that is done this way, we used to use your suggested code with another lib, now we are changing the lib and we need to provide the same interfaces

Comment: @user3908406, But why not just write `runTransaction2` in your own code? Are `createClient` and the other used functions private?

Comment: I thought about that, i looked into the lib, it is very complex. Not quite sure if I can replicate exactly